# Can not install RStudio Server on new Ubuntu server

Tags: 16.04, r, aws, rstudio

I launched an instance on AWS, with Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.
The instance is new and I only used the following commands from start;

First, i used apt-get update and created a username

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo adduser <username>
```

Next, I installed R, using

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And i added the following line to the list at the end:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

Then I Install R, using:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 51716619E084DAB9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

And finally I install R studio server, using:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-1.0.153-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.0.153-amd64.deb
```

R is installed correctly, I can type the command 'R' and use it.
But RStudio Server is not installed. I get the following message:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-89:~$ sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.0.153-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done

RStudio Server
 RStudio is a set of integrated tools designed to help you be more productive with R. It includes a console, syntax-highlighting editor that supports direct code execution, as well as tools for plotting, history, and workspace management.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
(Reading database ... 64867 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rstudio-server-1.0.153-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio-server (1.0.153) over (1.0.153) ...
Setting up rstudio-server (1.0.153) ...
useradd: user 'rstudio-server' already exists
groupadd: group 'rstudio-server' already exists
```

So it states 'rstudio-server already exists', which is weird cause i just launched this instance and did not do anything else except what I mentioned above. I tried once more with a different version of R studio server (on a different instance) but got the same problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: +1 for including all the commands you have ever run :)

Comment: That doesn't necessarily indicate a problem - see this previous question [Install RStudio: “ 'rstudio-server' already exists”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771314/install-rstudio-rstudio-server-already-exists)

Comment: These "useradd: user 'rstudio-server' already exists" and "groupadd: group 'rstudio-server' already exists" are warnings, not errors.

Comment: While agreeing with the above, I must also alert you to the fact that you used the wrong repo *trusty* (14.04)because you're running *xenial* (16.04). You have to adapt old instructions for the new releases.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Indeed it where warnings and no errors, but when I continued to my browser (after opening port 8787 in my AWS security group settings) and tried to access R studio server from there it did not work. And these warnings where the only clue of something going wrong... However, today I tried again and it worked fine. Without any changes to my settings.